# How to show these complex conjugates of exponential functions

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm supposed to show that the $\overline{e^z}$ is equal to $e^{\displaystyle\overline z}$, and I'm not really sure where to start!

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Well, write down the real and imaginary parts of $e^z$. What are they? Now write down the real and imaginary parts of $e^{\overline{z}}$. What are they? Now stare at it for a while.

Comment: @user296602 if z = x+iy, then the real part would be e^x and the imaginary would be e^iy, but are we allowed to define z like this if that wasn't included in the original problem?

Comment: $e^{a+ib}=e^a(\cos b + i \sin b)$. Now start.

Comment: @StrugglingMathStudent No, the real part is not $e^x$. You'll need to use Euler's formula.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a different approach from those in comments.

It's well known that $z\mapsto\overline{z}$ is a continuous, additive and multiplicative map.
Thus
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\overline{e^z} & = \overline{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n!}}
& = \overline{\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{z^k}{k!}} \\
& = \lim_{n\to\infty}\overline{\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{z^k}{k!}}
& = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{\overline{z}^k}{k!} \\
& = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\overline{z}^n}{n!}
& = e^{\overline{z}},
\end{split}
\end{equation}
as desired.

Comment: This is actually how it should be done! Nice +1

Comment: Could you please explain why the third equation is correct?

Comment: @hieppm it follows from the continuity of $z\mapsto\overline{z}$ that if $x_n\to x$ then $\overline{x_n}\to\overline{x}$